# Git clone --recursive makes file non executable

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have 2 repositories: [`gs-webui-test-beans`](https://github.com/guy-mograbi-at-gigaspaces/gs-webui-test-beans) and [`selenium-drivers`](https://github.com/guy-mograbi-at-gigaspaces/selenium-drivers).

`selenium-drivers` is a submodule in `gs-webui-test-beans`.

The file `chromedriver_linux64_2.1/chromedriver` should be executable on Linux after clone.

When I clone `selenium-drivers` it is indeed executable.

When I do `git clone --recursive` on `gs-webui-test-beans`  I check that file again and I see it is not executable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this still happens with the latest version of git, this is better suited as a bug report to the git developers...

Comment: ok. I will report this as a bug. I thought maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you try specifying the `--recurse-submodules` option?

Comment: --rescurse-submodules resolved this. Now I just need to figure out how to tell quickbuild to use this flag.

Comment: @devnull can you explain more about this flag?

Comment: @guymograbi It initializes all submodules using their default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init the submodules.  Either do

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

after the clone, or specify the `--recurse-submodules` option for [git clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

> `--recurse-submodules`
>
> After the clone is created, initialize all submodules within, using their default settings.
>   This is equivalent to running 
>   `git submodule update --init --recursive` immediately after the
>   clone is finished. This option is ignored if the cloned repository
>   does not have a worktree/checkout (i.e. if any of `--no-checkout`/`-n`,
>   `--bare`, or `--mirror` is given)